# Dynamic routing in Vue.js, showing `this.$route.params.id` in html

Tags: vue.js

I have a page that uses dynamic routing.

I have a "jobs" page that lists all jobs. One you click one job, it gives you the detail of that one job.

Jobs HTML page uses the following (snippets excludes ul/li tags):

```
<vue-panel v-for="job in jobs" v-if="filterJob(job)" v-bind:key="job.id">

Job: {{job.title}}<br>
Description: {{job.description}}<br>
Salary: ${{job.salary}}<br>
Date Posted: {{job.datePosted}}<br>

<router-link :to="`/job/${job.id}`">Learn More</router-link>
```

Clicking learn more leads to the correct job page. But how do I dynamically show just that specific job?

In the Job page, within the script I have:

```
  created() {
    console.log(this.$route.params.id); // prints value of :id
  },
```

Via console log I see that it has access to the correct job page. But it is not dynamically showing that one job on the page. What needs to be in the HTML to access a specific job?

HTML of job page, as of now (excludes the ul/li tags):

```
<vue-panel v-bind:key="job.id">

Job: {{job.title}}<br>
Description: {{job.description}}<br>
Salary: ${{job.salary}}<br>
Date Posted: {{job.datePosted}}<br>
```

Comment: What is the single job page displaying?  Everything, or nothing?  Within your second page, how is the `job` variable being set?

Comment: @MikeB., `job` page displays nothing. `Jobs` page shows a list of all jobs accurately and correctly redirects to the `job/:id` page correctly. Not sure if I understand your last question. `data():` has `job:[]` and `id: ""` listed. Here's just the `job` page: https://jsfiddle.net/runningraptor/97nyrvk5/5/

Comment: `job` is empty array? How do you set value for this variable?

Comment: @ittus, I am reading the `jobs` array from a static JSON file.

Comment: It sounds like you’re successfully getting the job ID from the route params, so you just need to use that to set the “job” data variable so that the page can access it and display it (`job` should probably start as an object instead of an array).  You can do that in your created() function, i.e `this.job = jobs.find(j => j.id == this.$route.params.id);`   If you don’t have the `.find(...)` func, `.filter(...)[0]` should do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I built a similiar project and did the following.

router.js:

```
{
  path: '/jobs/:id',
  name: 'JobSingle',
  component: JobSingle
}
```

jobs.vue

```
<router-link :to="{name:'JobSingle', params:{id:job._id}}">
  {{ job.title }}
</router-link>
```

For more question you can have a look at my project here: github.com/markusdanek/t2w-vue

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access by HTML you have to not bind key.

```
mounted(){
        document.getElementById("H1").setAttribute("key", this.$route.params.id);
        console.log('alex : ',document.getElementById("H1"));
      }
```

[image]
When you use it by vue, you can't do by v-bind as type:

This works:

```
 <div :type="$route.params.id">Verticals Statistics</div>
```

This don't work:

```
 <div :key="$route.params.id">Verticals Statistics</div>
```

So you'll have to trick for passing a :key by vue, or as you did, with :

```
<div v-for='id in [$route.params.id]' :key="id">Verticals Statistics</div>
```

But it will not apear in HTML code.

You have to put an id on each and create the key attribute in the mounted part.